# How do I select a complete dataGridView Row when the user clicks a cell of that row?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView` and I need that when the user clicks on any cell the whole row that contains this cell is selected too. (it has multiselect disbaled) 
I tried getting the `currentRowIndex` like this

```
 int Index = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

However, I am not sure how to use the index in order to select that row.
Tried this and about other six ways with no success:

```
dataGridView1.Select(Index);
```

Do you know a way I can do this?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You need to set datagridview's `SelectionMode` to `FullRowMode`.

Note: In Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.5 the property is called [`FullRowSelect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectionmode?view=netframework-4.5).

Comment: Hahah Much more simpler than I thought. Thank you.

Comment: Use: `dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;`

Answer (score 9):

If you want the row selected programatically, you would use the datagridview's cell click event: shown in VB.net and C#

VB.Net

```
Private Sub dgvGrid_CellClick(sender as System.Object, e as System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvGrid.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex < 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    intIndex = e.RowIndex
    dgvGrid.Rows(intIndex).Selected = True
Exit Sub
```

C#

```
private void dgvRptTables_CellClick(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0) {
        return;
    }

    int index = e.RowIndex;
    dgvGrid.Rows[index].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: How will I bind the event with datagridview?

Answer (score 8):

In the DataGridView properties,
Set

- MultiSelect -> True
- SelectionMode -> FullRowSelect

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Results.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';";
            row.CssClass = "rowHover";
            row.ToolTip = "Click row to view person's history";
            row.Attributes.Add("onclick", this.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.Results,"Select$" & r.RowIndex , true));
        }
    }

    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//class to store ID (Pri. Key) value of selected row from DataGridView
public class Variables
{
   public static string StudentID;
}                                  

//This is the event call on cell click of the DataGridView
private void dataGridViewDisplay_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   Variables.StudentID =this.dataGridViewDisplay.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
//textBoxName is my form field where I set the value of Name Column from the Selected row from my DataGridView 

   textBoxName.Text = this.dataGridViewDisplay.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

   dateTimePickerDOB.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dataGridViewDisplay.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
}
```

[Take a look at My DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHFQT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can Do this: May be it can help you.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex>0)
        {
            int rowindex = e.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow row= this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another possible answer because none of these seemed to work for my case or required extra event callbacks that aren't needed. Put this in your button click.

```
foreach (DataGridViewTextBoxCell item in NAMEOFDATAGRIDVIEW.SelectedCells)
        {
            item.OwningRow.Selected = true;
        }
```