# get value from selected row datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to get value from datagridview.

```
int selectedrowindex = dgvTable.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvTable.Rows[selectedrowindex];

String id = selectedRow.Cells["F_id"].Value.ToString();
```

But I get the value of the next row (row_index + 1). Variable `selectedrowindex` is correct, but value of `selectedRow` is wrong.

Comment: Did you debug your code and check what your `dgvTable` has exactly as a rows?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and found out that `selectedrowindex` is correct, but `selectedRow` returns next value.

Comment: Please visit this link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260843/getting-data-from-selected-datagridview-row-and-which-event

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672693/how-do-i-select-a-complete-datagridview-row-when-the-user-clicks-a-cell-of-that

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578144/index-of-currently-selected-row-in-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Use `datagridviewrow` and assigned as a variable.

```
datagridviewrow therowname = datagridviewname.rows[e.rowIndex];
```

After that, use this:

```
theobjectnamewantoassigned = therowname.cell[cellcolumnplaced].value;
```