# Get full row in single column select

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView`.
If I click over a column, it just selects a column like:

[image]

As you can see the Business Fax is selected, but my entire row is not, so in consequence, `this.dgComm.SelectedRows.Count` always throwd `0`, but if I click on first column like:

[image]

it selects the full row and `this.dgComm.SelectedRows.Count` throws `1`.

What I want to do is to prevent that zero. How can I select a full row if I just click in single column?

Regards.

Comment: What have you tried? Please give a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select a complete dataGridView Row when the user clicks a cell of that row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672693/how-do-i-select-a-complete-datagridview-row-when-the-user-clicks-a-cell-of-that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a property on the DataGridView entitled *SelectedMode*, ensure this is set to *FullRowSelect*

[image: Full Row Select]